# How to make an URL independant Facebook Application?

Tags: facebook

I'm working on a new module for TomatoCMS. Here you'll be able to post new content on the website and forward is to a fanpage on Facebook (as page admin).
While experimenting and trying to get things working, it seems like I HAVE TO put an application url ... Is this correct?

So I won't be able to reuse the module on another URL?
Is there a way to make it re-usable? (Not URL-specific)

I'm working in PHP (with Zend Framework) and the phpSDK.

Thanks for your insight :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i am getting it right you want to have your code module work on any other application's  domain url. If this is the case then  to admin pages you need access token which need appid and appsecret which are bount to the application url with you registered. so you can't do it without a url.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ... I'll have to rethink my application I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is late (older post) but it might be helpful to someone else perhaps.

From what I understand, if you're not designing an on line application (lets say for a program that runs on Windows), you would use::

https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html  as your redirect.

And then to attach the required permissions to the call, you'd add it as such::

https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html**&scope=email,user_online_presence,sms,offline_access**